# Can I change requests to a certain domain to go to my local webserver?

Tags: dns

Without modifying the hosts file? I want everyone in my LAN to be able to visit "internal.mycompany.com" and reach a webserver running on my localhost in LAN and nobody on the outside of the company should have access to that url. At the same time I dont want to have to change everyone's hosts file..
Is that possible?

Comment: Do you have a DNS server internally? What's your network environment like? Is everything connected to a single router? If you have a DNS server it should be trivial to set this up, it's a very common thing to do.

Comment: unfortunately im not in IT, I'm just a developer.

Comment: If your not bothered about getting fired you could give [dns spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing) a try.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your company has split-DNS setup, this should be as easy as requesting your IT department to add "internal.mycompany.com" to the internal DNS.  It does make it visible everywhere internally including outside of your LAN, but if nobody else knows about it that should be good enough.

Comment: Do you mean that different internal subnets of the same *LAN* will have access but not the WAN? The DNS server will not be listening to the WAN interface. The answer reads to me as if you meant that its Internet accessible.

Comment: "everywhere internally including outside of your LAN" doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Most company internal networks are made up of numerous LAN segments connected together with WAN links.  Think of a site in Atlanta and a site in Chicago.  You'll have at least one LAN in each location, and if those LANs are connected, they are connect with one or more WAN links.  A routing protocol builds out your layer 3 network, or intranet.  This does not mean it is Internet accessible, but it can be.  Your firewall, addressing scheme, and NAT rules determines what is "internal" and what is "external" from a public Internet P.O.V.

Comment: Thus, if you have DNS internally setup as "split" from the public DNS servers, then you can put the name into the internal DNS and it will be resolvable from anywhere internal, i.e., in either Atlanta or Chicago, but not visible or reachable on the public Internet.  Any good TCP/IP networking reference book can explain this if you're still lost.

Comment: With DNS servers, there isn't really a concept of LAN or WAN from it's point of view.  It has an IP address on a LAN segment and communicates internally either directly on the LAN it lives on, or out across the WAN to other LAN segments through it's default gateway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try the following - should be possible from what I know:

Just contact whoever is managing your internet domain/DNS entry (i.e. *mycompany.com*) and let them add a new subdomain *internal.mycompany.com* that will resolve to your local LAN IP.

It won't matter whether this domain can be resolved from the outside, since the LAN IP won't be valid on the internet (it's a LAN IP after all).

For example, if you set *internal.mycompany.com* to resolve to *192.168.1.2* this will always point to a local LAN computer with that name. If you're in your company LAN, it will point to the proper server. If you're in some internet cafe, it will point to a computer in the internet cafe (or some machine that doesn't exist).

Just keep in mind that this is potentially dangerous if you're writing or using some tool that doesn't verify the remote computer (like SSH). If you're unlucky (or someone is trying to attack you this way), you might connect to a server not under your control that's trying to fake being your server and stealing data, logins, etc.

Comment: ok but that attack vector is only possible if someone knows the full internal domain name, yes? and anyway, it's just supposed to be readonly, so it would work for my case

Comment: Yes, of course they'd first have to know your full internal domain name and then they'd have to setup the proper software to answer the request. Such attacks can easily be prevented if you employ some kind of certificate based authentication of the remote machine (like using an SSL certificate).